# How to get textbox values from gridview using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

How to textbox values from gridview on click of a linkbutton using jquery
here is my gridview

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvEmployee" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="Both">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Emailid") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkgettext" runat="server" Text="Gettextboxvalue"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I tried something like

```
  alert($(this).parent("td").parent("tr").find("input:text").val());
```

I Can able to find first value of a textbox
but facing a problem to get next textbox value i.e txtName from second td
Please suggest
Also suggest if you have any solution with javascript

Answer (score 1):

May this will help you...

```
    function GVtxtAmount() {
    var GVMaintainReceiptMaster = document.getElementById('<%= GVMaintainReceiptMaster.ClientID %>');

    for (var rowId = 1; rowId < GVMaintainReceiptMaster.rows.length; rowId++) {
        var txtbx = GVMaintainReceiptMaster.rows[rowId].cells[0].children[0];
        alert(txtbx.value);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use end selector as follows

```
 $( "[ @id *= 'txtEmail']" ).text();
```

Here is a good link about how to find the element like selection

```
[http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1003-Cool-jQuery-Predicate-Selectors.htm][1]
```

You will find like this

```
 //first find the tr 
 var tr= $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");
 and then use like selector with.

 var Email=$(this).parent("td").parent("tr").find($( "[ @id *= 'txtEmail']" )).val();
 var Name= $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").find($( "[ @id *= 'txtName']" )).val();
```

Comment: got solution  alert($(a).parent("td").parent("tr").find(".txtclass1").val());

Comment: do you know what are using. You are using a class selector. So if you have put css-classes then it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#<%=lnkgettext.ClientID %>').click(function(){
    var email=$(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('#<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>').val();        
    var name=$(this).parent('td').parent('tr').find('#<%=txtName.ClientID%>').val();
}
```

or

```
$(this).parent("td").parent("tr").each(function(){
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
        //Do whatever you want, you can use $(this) to get value of current cell
    })
})
```

Comment: it's a gridview so the it will change at the right time. there will be unique id's for every column.

Comment: What exactly do you want to say? Are you saying that the texbox controls will change their ID?

Comment: yes since it is a gridview and it will have many rows at runtime. With different id's like txtEmail_0 and txtEmail_1 etc and if the page is inherited by master page then it will be like ct0_txtEmail_0 etc

Comment: Yes, It will have many rows .. But the control names never change.. Have you tried my code?

Comment: can there be two control of same ie in asp.net ??

Comment: No, never.. In a gridview , all the controls are repeatedly filled with different values in every row.. But their ID's do not change with every new row..

Comment: Yes they are diffrent in every row like gvEmployee$ctl02$txtName gvEmployee$ctl03$txtName

Comment: var alltextbox=textBoxValues[0]+' '+textBoxValues[1]; giving character at 0 and 1 position and not enire string i.e if i have rakesh in 1st textbox and rakesh@yahoo.com in 2nd then it is giving me r a in alert

Comment: Try it out.. I've edited my code again.. ClientID was missing in previous codes.. Also Check for the new code I've posted.

Comment: it give me Error as The name 'txtName' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should work perfectly

```
$('a[id$=lnkgettext]').click(function(){
    var email=$(this).parent('tr').find('input[id=txtEmail]').val();        
    var name=$(this).parent('tr').find('input[id=txtName]').val();
    alert(email+" "+name);
}
```